# When MySQL get handshake errors PDO(or an Application) retry to get connection?

Tags: mysql

php 5.4.45
nginx 1.10.3
MySQL 5.6.27

I got MySQL error which says 
"ERROR 1129 (HY000): Host 'YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'".

And I google it, people say I should raise max_connect_errors numbers And I can do it.

But I have a question, When I got this error, MySQL documentation says It 
is caused by handshake error.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/host-cache-table.html

So I think there where a lot of handshake errors at least a hundred(the default numbers is 100), but there are no errors in php and nginx logs.

Does PDO retry to connect to DB when MySQL got handshake error until get connection.
I am wondering why there were must be handshake errors but there were no error logs on nginx and php.

I need any information not only php.

Sorry for my poor English, thank you.